# Analytic eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory, matrix-calculus, perturbation-theory

Is the following conclusion true?
Suppose $A,B$ are $n\times n$ complex Hermitian matrices. Then there exists real analytic functions $\lambda_i:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ where $1\leq i\leq n $ such that for each $t\in\mathbb R$, the set $\{\lambda_1(t)\dots,\lambda_n(t)\}$ is the set of all eigenvalues of $A+tB$ counting multiplicities and with respect to some orthonormal basis $A+tB=\text{diag}(\lambda_1(t),\dots,\lambda_n(t)).$

If this is true, is it also true for $A,B$ are Hermitian compact operators on $\ell_2$?

Comment: [Kato](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/kato1.pdf) p. 63. I haven't thought about "real analytic".

Comment: To the OP. On this website, usage is, if one is satisfied with an answer, then one upvotes it and (or) one gives the green ticket or, if one is not satisfied, then one writes why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$t\in \mathbb{R}\mapsto A+tB$ is analytic with values in the set of hermitian matrices. Then your conjecture is true.

cf. for the real symmetric case, my post in

[Do eigenvalues depend smoothly on the matrix elements of a diagonalizable matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510494/do-eigenvalues-depend-smoothly-on-the-matrix-elements-of-a-diagonalizable-matrix)

More generally, for the hermitian case or the operators, cf.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.4475.pdf

EDIT. Answer to the OP. The considered theorem is valid fo one real parameter. There are counter-examples when we are dealing with $2$ parameters.

EDIT. Answer to the OP.

Note also that when $A,B$ are invertible and $n$ is odd, "there is always some real $t$ s.t. $A+tB$ is not invertible". This last point is useless -I don't know why I wrote this-; there is a global analytic parameterization over $(-\infty,+\infty)$:

$A+tB=U(t)^*diag((\lambda_i(t))_i)U(t)$.

Comment: @Ioup. Alright. Meanwhile, I have looked for Rellich's theorem. The theorem is in vast generality. I want to ask the following. Let $A.B$ complex Hermitian matrix. Then for how big a domain in complex plain I can have a holomorphic choice of 'full' set of eigenvalues? I am assuming that both A and B are invertible and finite dimensional also.

Comment: @Ioup. Why do you bring in the invertible case?