# When is von Neumann entropy differentiable? (Edited)

Tags: mathematical-physics, matrix-calculus, entropy, statistical-mechanics

Given a smoothly time-dependent density matrix (positive-semidefinite matrix with trace 1) $\rho(t)$, its von Neumann entropy is defined as
$$
S(t)=\mathrm{Tr}(f(\rho(t))),\ f:[0,\infty)\ni x\mapsto -x\ln x\in\mathbb{R}\ (0\ln0=0).
$$
I want to know when $S(t)$ is differentiable.
If $\rho(t)$ has the same rank, then it is differentiable and we have
$$
S'(t)=-\mathrm{Tr}(\rho'(t)\ln\rho(t)).
$$
(Related question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333779/scalar-derivative-of-rm-trax-log-ax-where-ax-is-a-square-matrix). )
If the rank of $\rho(t)$ varies, I think $S(t)$ is not differentiable in general, because $f$ isn't (one-sided) differentiable at $x=0$.

However, some mathematical physicists have stated that $S(t)$ is differentiable without the rank assumption for the special $\rho(t)$ (Equation (1)&(3) in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.5931) and Equation (10)&(13), (16)&(26) in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.0680)).

Specifically, this is the case where $\rho(t)$ is a matrix on the tensor product space $\mathcal{H}_A\otimes\mathcal{H}_B$ and is given by using partial traces as
$$
\rho(t)=\mathrm{Tr}_B(e^{-iHt}\rho(0)e^{iHt}), 
$$
where $H$ is some self-adjoint matrix on $\mathcal{H}_A\otimes\mathcal{H}_B$.
They state that the derivative of $S(t)$ (at $t=0$) is expressed as
$$
S'(0)=-\mathrm{Tr}(H[\rho(0),\ln\rho(0)_A\otimes I_B]). 
$$

Is this equation still correct when the rank of $\rho(0)_A$ changes, and if so, what does $\ln \rho(0)_A$ mean?
Furthermore, how can this equation be shown?
If you have a counterexample, I would like to know. Thanks!

***Edit:*** Kurt.G [presented](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4868874/1293312) the abstract condition that the eigenvalues should satisfy. Is this condition satisfied in the above case (entropy of the subsystem)? If so, why?
I suppose we could use the results on the analyticity of the eigenvalues(e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3513737/1293312) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3726354/1293312)), but I am not sure of the details.

Comment: Where exactly in the related post does someone claim that the rank matters?

Comment: In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333779/scalar-derivative-of-rm-trax-log-ax-where-ax-is-a-square-matrix?noredirect=1&lq=1) they assumed $A(x)$ is nonsingular.

Answer (score 1):

We know that when $\rho$ describes a pure state then $\rho^2=\rho$ and
$\rho\log\rho=\rho\log\rho^2=2\rho\log\rho$ so that $S=-\operatorname{tr}(\rho\log\rho)=0\,.$

- This shows that $S(t)\equiv 0$ is equivalent to $\rho(t)$ being pure.
- In particular, $S(t)$ is differentiable and $\rho(t)$ is singular.

A typical pure state has density matrix
$$
\rho=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}\quad\text{ or }\quad\rho=\pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}\,.
$$
A typical mixed state is
$$
\rho(t)=\pmatrix{a(t)&0\\0&b(t)}\quad\text{ with }\quad a(t)+b(t)=1\,, \;a(t),b(t)\ge 0\,.
$$
Then, if $a(t),b(t)>0\,,$
$$
S(t)=a(t)\log a(t)+b(t)\log b(t)\,.
$$
l'Hospital allows to extend this continuously to the case $a(t)=0$ or $b(t)=0$ with the convention $0\log 0=0$ (compatible with pure states). This $S(t)$ is obviously differentiable whenever $a$ and $b$ are differentiable regardless if the rank
of $\rho(t)$ changes or not.

***Edit:*** When $a$ reaches zero at $t_0$  we need one extra condition
to ensure the differentiability of $a(t)\log a(t)$ at this point:
$$
\lim_{t\to t_0}\frac{a(t)\log a(t)}{t-t_0}=0\,.
$$
In particular $a'(t_0)$ must be zero.

Assuming that an analogous condition
holds for $b\,,$ the derivative of $S$ is
$$
S'(t)=a'(t)\log a(t)+a'(t)+b'(t)\log b(t)+b'(t)\,.
$$
The terms with $a$ are zero at $t_0\,$ and an analogous statement
holds for the terms with $b\,.$

Comment: It certainly seems to follow from l'Hospital's theorem, but I have two questions.
1. how is the existence of the limit of $a'(t)\ln a(t)$ (or $b'(t)\ln b(t)$) guaranteed?
2. How can [this formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333779/scalar-derivative-of-rm-trax-log-ax-where-ax-is-a-square-matrix/1333892#1333892) be modified? For a matrix that is not positive-definite, its logarithm can only be defined on its support.

Comment: This should be addressed in the edit. Every log appears in a product with $a(t)$ or $a'(t)$ and by the benign convention $0\log 0 =0$ we can make there is no problem with that.

Comment: Thank you! Are there any simple conditions on $a(t)$ or $\rho(t)$ for the existence of such a limit as above? For example, does the example I wrote in the question satisfy this condition?

Comment: @tuna Given the multiple questions that you are having I suggest you edit your post and write out the partial trace of $e^{-iHt}\rho(0)e^{iHt}\,.$ Multiple links and equation numbers are not very reader friendly.