# Smooth Sylvester's law of inertia

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, matrix-calculus, bilinear-form, smooth-functions

Let $Q(x)$ be a smooth symetric matrix with constant signature $(p,q,k)$ where $x$ belong in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $p+q+k=m$.

**Question:** Locally around $x_0$, does an invertible matrix $P(x)$ of size $m$ exists such that,

$$
P^T(x) Q(x) P(x) = \begin{pmatrix} Id_p &0&0\\0&-Id_q&0\\ 0&0&0_k\end{pmatrix}
$$

**/!\** I do not require that $P(x)$ is the jacobian of some diffeormorphism.

**Proposition of Proof:**

1. If $Q(x_0)$ is invertible and all its eignevalue are simple, then this property is locally preserved. Hence the basis of orthonormal vectors depend smoothly on the point.
2. If $Q(x_0)$ has a multiple eigenvalue, then locally the eigen hypersurface can split into multiple eigen hypersurfacesof smaller dimension. However because the bilinear form asociated with $Q$ is symmetric the vectors spanning the multiple smaller hypersurfaces will converge to a basis of the eigenhypersurface. Hence the transformation is still smooth.
3. If $det(Q(x_0))=0$, then locally we have $\mathbb{R}^n=\ker Q \oplus^{\perp}rg(Q)$. The kernel of $Q$ is determined by a set of equations, by the implicit functions theorem we can express the vector spanning this kernel by smooth functions. As the image of $Q$ is orthogonal to the kernel, then it is also spanned by smooth functions and we can express $Q$ in this subspace and repeat the previous argument.

Comment: To the OP. On this website, usage is, if one is satisfied with an answer, then one upvotes it and (or) one gives the green ticket or, if one is not satisfied, then one writes why

Comment: I know, I try to  unserstand your answer for know.

Answer (score 1):

A necessary condition for local-existence of a $C^{\infty}$ function $P(x)$ is that $k$ is locally constant. -indeed, by continuity, $p,q$ are locally constant-

Conversely, if $k$ is locally constant, it suffices that the eigenvalues and a basis of (unit length) eigenvectors of $Q(x)$ are globally $C^{\infty}$ parametrizable.

When $Q$ is only smooth, that is -in general- false. Yet, it's true when $Q$ is analytic; in this case, $P$ is an analytic function.

cf. my post in

[Do eigenvalues depend smoothly on the matrix elements of a diagonalizable matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510494/do-eigenvalues-depend-smoothly-on-the-matrix-elements-of-a-diagonalizable-matrix)

EDIT. To the OP. I see that you didn't understand my post. More precisely, if we do the following reasoning: If $Q(x)$ is ANALYTIC, then

i) There is an analytic parameterization of the eigen-elements of $Q(x)$: $Q(x)=U^T(x)diag(\lambda_i(x))U(x)$ where the $U(x)$ are orthogonal matrices.

ii) Let $P(x)=U(x)diag(\mu_i(x))$, where $\mu_i(x)=|\lambda_i(x)|^{-1/2}$ if $\lambda_i(x)\not= 0$ and $=1$ otherwise. Then $P(x)$ is ANALYTIC and answers the question.